# Can't scrape some fields from a webpage using requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to find a way to get three fields from a webpage using requests. If I try like ***[this](https://pastebin.com/PFgF0syx)*** using selenium, I can fetch them accordingly. However, I do not wish to go that route. Instead, I would like to fetch the three fields from that webpage using requests as there are most of the times alternatives, as in `hidden api`, `script tag` e.t.c. I tried searching for them using dev tools but failed miserably, so I though to look for any help.

[website link](https://www.gofundme.com/f/toronto-tiny-shelters)

The three fields I'm after:

[image]

I've tried with:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = "https://www.gofundme.com/f/toronto-tiny-shelters"
headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36"}

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get(link,headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    donors = soup.select_one("[data-element-id='btn_donors'] > span").text
    shares = soup.select_one("span.text-stat:has(> span:contains('shares')) > span.text-stat-value").text
    followers = soup.select_one("span.text-stat:has(> span:contains('followers')) > span.text-stat-value").text
    print(donors,shares,followers)
```

> How can I grab those three fields from that site using requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scrape the API will get the exact number of each data.

Try code below:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.83 Safari/537.36',
}

response = requests.get('https://gateway.gofundme.com/web-gateway/v1/feed/toronto-tiny-shelters/counts', headers=headers)

d = response.json()["references"]["counts"]
print("donors: ", d['total_donations'])
print("shares: ", d['social_share_total'])
print("followers: ", d['campaign_hearts'])
```

Result:

```
donors:  3742
shares:  4369
followers:  3708
```

Comment: Those `k`s after each number made it difficult to find them in dev tools. They indeed are within page source in a script tag. Thanks a lot @jizhihaoSAMA for your solution. It did the trick perfectly.